# excecute angular controller from foundation's reveal modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, forms, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to load a form using foundation's reveal modal, i need to run a angular controller inside the form to enable the form submission using ajax and not the default post/refresh behaviour.

this is my main view:

```
<html lang="es" ng-app="crm">
<body>
<script>
    var crmapp =  angular.module('crm', ['ng.django.forms',"ui.select"]);

</script>
<a data-reveal-id="idmodal" class="fi-burst" data-reveal-ajax="true" href="/operador/clientes/saldos/anadir/13">Añadir Pago</a>

<div id="idmodal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="false">
</div>
</body>
```

and this is my form:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="dummy">
    <h2>Añadir Pago</h2>
    <ng-form>
        <label>Fecha de Cobro:</label>
        <label>Valor:</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns small-offset-5 small-7">
                <button class="buttons success round" ng-click="alert(5)">Añadir</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-form>

</div>

<script>
crmapp.controller('dummy', function($scope) { $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';console.log("bye"); });
</script>
<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

any "regular" javascript code in the form is called, but the angular controller isnt working. what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to work with `ng-click` and controller:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/bq9sez3o/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="dummy">
         <h2>Añadir Pago</h2>
        <ng-form>
            <label>Fecha de Cobro:</label>
            <label>Valor:</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columns small-offset-5 small-7">
                    <button class="buttons success round" ng-click="greeting()">Añadir</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-form>
    </div>
<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>

</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = function () {
            console.log("bye");
        };
}]);
```